# SQL: calculate value based on two different conditions

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below is my table schema:- Appointments

```
--------------------------------------
| schID | appointment_date | amount | location |
--------------------------------------
```

I want to fire a single query where I can get the sum of amount, total appointment_date this year i.e 2016 and remaining appointment_date this year i.e 2016.

So I wrote the below query to calculate the above fields:-

```
SELECT sum(a.amount) as total, 
       count(distinct a.appointment_date) as total_appointment, 
       count(distinct a2.appointment_date) as remaining appointments 
from Appointments a 
LEFT JOIN Appointments a2 ON a.schID = a2.schID 
WHERE a2.appointment_date > GETDATE() AND year(a.appointment_date) = 2016
group by a.location
```

The above query doesnt return value as per requirement :(

The database belongs to SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *conditional aggregation* for this:

```sql
SELECT sum(amount) as total, 
       count(appointment_date) as total_appointment, 
       count(DISTINCT CASE 
                WHEN appointment_date > GETDATE() AND YEAR(appointment_date) = 2016 
                  THEN DATE(appointment_date)
             END) as remaining appointments 
from Appointments a 
group by a.location
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply, but how can we include "distinct" in case section such that only unique dates gets counted.

Comment: @Villie Have you also added the `DATE(appointment_date)` after `THEN`? The `DATE` function is only necessary in case `appointment_date` is not of type `DATE`.

Comment: Yea I forgot to change the return value from 1 to appintment_date. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need a `join` for this type of query:

```
SELECT sum(a.amount) as total, count(a.appointment_date) as total_appointment, 
       sum(case when a.appointment_date > getdate() then 1 else 0
           end) as remaining appointments
from Appointments a 
where year(a.appointment_date) = year(GETDATE() );
```

If you need the breakdown by location, then include `location` in both the `select` and `group by` clauses.